# Can the azure devops free tier run a self hosted job in parallel with a free hosted agent?

Tags: azure-devops

I just set up a self hosted build server to augment the 1800 free minutes we get on the free hosted agent.

It appears to me that the system is only scheduling one of them at a time. I would have expected that I could have used both in parallel for free.

Is this not the case?

If not, if I purchase a single parallel job license (about US15 / month from memory?), will that allow me to run the two agents concurrently?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achievable. You need assign self hosted agent and free hosted agent to your jobs respectively to run them in parallel.

For example:

```
jobs:
- job: A
  pool:
    name: "free hosted agent pool"
  steps:

- job: B
  pool:
    name: "self hosted agent pool"
  steps:
```

However i found Microsoft-hosted agent can run in parallel with only one self hosted agent for private project.

Additionally:
Mirosoft provides 10 free parallel jobs for public project and 1 free parallel job for private. [For more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thanks for this. Is it possible to specify a number of agent pools (eg Azure Pipelines and Default (for self hosted)) and have devops just pick the next free agent in either one?

Comment: Agents are organized into pools[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops). free hosted agents and self hosted agents are in the different agent pools.And you can only define one pool in a job. I do not think it is possible.